# jinja replace special char

Tags: replace, jinja2

I am trying to replace a point by an underscore using jinja :

```
{{ "6.1"|replace(".", "_") }}
{{ "6.1"|replace(".", "_") | safe }}
```

expected result : 6_1

real result : 61

It seems that underscore is not interpreted correctly.

Do you have any tips ?

Thanks,

Bob

Answer (score 5):

i tested it and got the expected result:

```
>>> import jinja2
>>> t = jinja2.Template('{{ "6.1" | replace(".", "_") }}')
>>>
>>> print(t.render())
6_1
```

refer to https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#replace, there's no restriction or special character with the **second parameter**, the replacement string, since it's of type string.